# How to change a letter or 2 into a number that you preset?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that is suppose to change a note in concert pitch to a pitch on a non-concert pitched instrument. Any who. I have this already have.

```
F=5
E#=5
Fb=4
E=4
Eb=3
Ds=3
D=2
Db=1
Cs=1
C=0
B#=0
Cb=-1
B=-1
Bb=-2
A#=-2
A=-3
Ab=-4
G#=-4
G=-5
Gb=-6
F#=-6
```

I named all the # letters s in program cause # in python makes things a comment

And the user types a letter that they want to hear on the piano.

```
snote=raw_input("What is the concert note that you want to play? ")
```

Then what the instrument is pitched in.

```
instr=raw_input("What pitch is your instrument in? ")
```

Then the program prints the note that the instrument needs to play to play the concert pitch

so want to Concert Bb on a Bb pitch(-2) instrument is Ab.
C=(0)

```
if note=="BB":
    newnote=Bb-A
print newnote
```

This part I'm struggling with is trying to take a letter that the user types in to a number so the program can do the math then print out the transposed note. If anyone knows how to change a letter to a preset number I will greatly appreciate it because I also need to do this for another program I am trying to do. But thanks for trying if you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You are really going about this the wrong way. You should make a dictionary to convert user input into a specific number. Here's an example. I used your method of replacing the `#` with s.

```
notesDict = {"F" : 5, "Es" : 5, "Fb" : 4, "E" : 4}
key = input("What key do you want to hear ").replace("#","s")
print(notesDict[key])

# What key do you want to hear: E#
# 5
```

Comment: Note that `input` only really works this way in Python 3; for Python 2.7 (which OP is using) `raw_input` is still the way to go.

Comment: That's true, didn't notice op wasn't on 3.

Comment: As the key is a string, they don't need to replace the `#` with an `s`, they could just use `{..., "E#" : 5, ..}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
notes = {"F" : 5, "E#" : 5, "Fb" : 4, "E" : 4}
value = raw_input()
print(notes[value]) if value in notes else print("Invalid input")
```

Also # is treated as a comment when python sees it as a seperate token. If the # is inside `"E#"` for eg. python will treat just like any other character.

Comment: You also need to replace any `#` the user types in with an `s`

Comment: @Racialz Where is that specified by the OP?

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to type Es if you want to hear E#. Op says `And the user types a letter that they want to hear on the piano.` he doesn't say `and op types a special converted string that isn't actually what he wants to hear`

Comment: It doesn't makes sense either to have a dictionary mapping with Es when you want E#

Comment: Using try except is not a right way of doing stuff in Python. In that case you can just ask if value is in that dictionary.

Comment: @LiorMagen agreed. Fixed.